# "expired" vs "is expired"

Tags: word-usage

How should I use this word ?

> Deadline required by the agreement **expired**.

or

> Deadline required by the agreement **is/was(?) expired**.

What is the correct usage ? if both are correct grammatically, what is the difference in the meanings.

Thanks.

Comment: Open for discussion - can a deadline actually expire. It can be reached, or pass, but can it, itself, expire? Just thinking out loud really.

Comment: I wasn't questioning the word 'expire' I was questioning whether a deadline could actually do that. The deadline itself merely passed, the opportunity to do [whatever it was] has expired.

Comment: @Tetsujin: a deadline can expire, although it admittedly isn't used very much: [CBS](http://www.cbsnews.com/videos/isis-prisoner-swap-deadline-expires-now-what/) and [the Wall Street Journal](http://www.wsj.com/articles/jordan-demands-proof-pilot-is-alive-before-prisoner-swap-1422532012) used it recently. The British [Mirror](http://www.mirror.co.uk/sport/football/news/david-gold-slams-daniel-levy-5096150) uses it too.

Comment: @oerkelens - nice bit of research, tyvm :)

Answer (score 5):

Unless you are writing headlines, you need to include a definite article before *deadline*.

Then all three options you mentioned can be correct, it is simply a matter of which tense you mean to use (and I will include a fourth one). However, a deadline *actively* expires, it doesn't get expired by something else, so we don't use a *passive* construction!

It *is* possible to use *expired* as an adjective, to describe the *state* of a deadline. *The deadline is expired* has the same construction as *the deadline is tight*.

Simple present: the deadline expires, now or at a given moment:

> The deadline required by the agreement expires.
>   The deadline required by the agreement expires next week.

Simple past: it expired at some point in the past:

> The deadline required by the agreement expired.
>   The deadline required by the agreement expired last week.

Present perfect: at this moment in time, the deadline has expired. It described the current state of the deadline: it expired at some moment in he past:

> The deadline required by the agreement has expired.

Past perfect: at some moment in the past, the deadline had already expired, prior to the moment we are talking about:

> When you asked for those changes, the deadline required by the agreement had already expired.

Comment: Before seeing [these](https://www.google.ro/search?q=%22is+expired%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1910,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=66TQVLmdCMTbarXKgqAO) books I perfectly agreed with you. However it seems that some people do use the passive. Now I’m quite confused.

Comment: Tetsujin is correct. Deadlines do not "expire".

Comment: @BrianHitchcock: see my comment under Tetsujin's remark. It is used, though not common.

Comment: @LucianSava: indeed, as when _expired_ is used as an adjective, it can be used with a copula. But that is not actually passive. Note that "was expired" mostly returns result for _breathing out_.

Comment: I understand, not quite perfect but can get the point. Anyway I think your answer is very good. +1